# ImageBrush with async ImageSource doesn't always render

Tags: wpf

I'm rendering images in a WPF `ItemsControl` as follows:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Border
      Height="200"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      CornerRadius="9,9,0,0">
      <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush
          ImageSource="{Binding MediaUrl, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True}"
          RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="LowQuality"
          RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
          Stretch="UniformToFill" />
      </Border.Background>
    </Border>
  </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The `ImageSource` is bound to a URL pointing to an image server on the Web (HTTP protocol)

Sometimes the `ImageBrush` doesn't render but if I move the mouse over something in the program that that has to draw (a button that highlights on mouseover for instance), the image renders.

Is there something I can do to nudge WPF to render the `ImageBrush` after it loads?

.NET Core 3.1

Comment: Does it only happen when you set `IsAsync=True` on the ImageSource Binding? Setting that seems pointless anyway, since the loading of a BitmapImage or BitmapFrame from a remote URI is done asynchronously by default. And setting `Mode=OneWay` is of course also redundant.

Comment: Happens whether I use IsAsync or not.

Comment: Also without `RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"`?

Comment: Removing `RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"` makes no difference either.

Comment: I'd recommend to reduce the amount of WPF magic that happens behind the scenes by doing the web request manually, either by changing the property type from string/Uri to ImageSource, or by implementing a Binding Converter. Download the web resource and create a BitmapImage or BitmapFrame from a MemoryStream. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46709476/1136211

Comment: Also, it seems related to `ImageBrush` or maybe `ImageSource`. If I remove `Border` and use `Image` it works just fine. However, I really would like to control the radius of each corner of the image.

Comment: I could see using a binding converter. Would the lifetime of the bitmap be the same as the magic WPF binding (kinda guessing it would)? I'm using this in a virtualizing stack panel.

Comment: The magic simply calls the built-in ImageSourceConverter, which returns a BitmapFrame that is potentially cached with the URI as cache key. However, if an Image element works, but an ImageBrush doesn't, doing the download manually will most likely not be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe you could simply use an Image element that has its OpacityMask set to some Brush with those round corners, e.g. a VisualBrush with your Border as Visual, or an appropriate DrawingBrush.

Comment: I made a visual brush out of the image and used it as the background the border which is similar to what you were suggesting. Thanks.

Comment: That's even simpler. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

From the discussion above I put together this solution. `VisualBrush` allowed me to use an `Image` instead of `ImageBrush`, which behaves better in my use case.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Border
      Height="200"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      CornerRadius="9,9,0,0">
      <Border.Background>
        <VisualBrush
          AlignmentY="Top"
          Stretch="UniformToFill">
          <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Image
              RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="LowQuality"
              Source="{Binding MediaUrl}" />
          </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
      </Border.Background>
    </Border>
  </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```